# What is the joint probability of $(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability

> We have two cubic dies $A$ and $B$.
>
> The die $A$ has the numbers $-2, -2, 1,1,1,1$ on its faces which are equiprobable.
>
> The die $B$ has the numbers $-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3$ on its faces which probability is as follow:
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|lcr}
> Number & -2  & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3   \\
> \hline
> Probability & p & \frac{p}{2} & \frac{p}{4} & \frac{p}{8}& \frac{p}{16} & \frac{p}{32}\\
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> - Let $X$ be the random variable which represents the number on the face of die $A$ on each roll.
> - Let $Y$ be the random variable which represents the absolute value of the sum of numbers on face of each die.
>
>   1. What is the table distribution of X.
>   2. What is the table distribution of $(X,Y).$

---

1. $$
   \begin{array}{c|lcr}
   X & \text{-2} & \text{1} \\
   \hline
   p(X=1) & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\
   \end{array}
   $$
2. To determine the table of distribution of $(X,Y)$ I need to fill the table

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
\hline
- 2 & p(-2,0)  & p(-2,1)& p(-2, 2) & p(-2, 3) & p(-2, 4)  \\
1  & p(1, 0) & p(1, 1) & p(1, 2)& p(1, 3) & p(1, 4) \\
\end{array}
$$

I know that $p(X,Y) = p(X|Y). p(Y)$

I don't know how to compute $p(-2,0) = p(X=-2|Y=0).p(Y=0)$ so I can fill the table. Thank you.

Comment: "Let X be the random variable which represents the number on the face of the die on each roll." Which die?

Comment: @mzp Die $A$. I just edited it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z$ be the outcome of the second dice, then we have $Y = |X+Z|$ and $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

Hence, if I know $Y$ and $X$, then $Z = -X \pm Y$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{=}{-2},Y{=}1)&~=~\mathsf P(X{=}{-2}, Z{=}1)+\mathsf P(X{=}{-}2, Z{=}3)\\[1ex]
&~=~\mathsf P(X{=}{-}2)~\mathsf P(Z{=}1) + \mathsf P(X{=}{-}2)~\mathsf P(Z{=}3)\\[1ex]
&~=~\mathsf P(X{=}{-}2)~\big(\mathsf P(Z{=}1)+ \mathsf P(Z{=}3)\big)\\[1ex]
&~=~\frac13 \left( \frac{p}{8}+ \frac{p}{32} \right)
\end{align}$$

Note that $X$ takes value $-2,1$ rather than $-1,2$ in your table.

Comment: I don't understand $ P(-2,1) = (-2,1) + p(X,B)$. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: oops, typo, it should be $Z$. If the first dice gives me $-2$ and the second dice gives me $1$, then the sum would be $-1$ and the absolute value is $1$.  If the first dice gives me $-2$ and the second dice gives me $3$, then the sum would be $1$ and the absolute value is $1$. I have included more explanation.

Comment: I don't understand $P(X,Z) = (-2,1)) + P((X,Z)$. I am not familiar with the notations $(-2, 1))$ and $P((X,Z)$ with double parentheses.

Comment: let me edit the notation

Comment: Last question please, why $P(-2,1) = P(-2, 1) + P(-2,3)$ ?

Comment: I should have edited the LHS that I meant to mean $P(X=-2, Y=1)$. $Z$ can take two possible values as $Z=-X \pm Y$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. =)